# How to replace only first instance of a value in a list which consists of multiple groups?

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing, replace

I have 2 lists and I want to change the elements of 2nd list based on groups of 1st list. Example I have:-

```
a=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
b=['','','l2','22','','','','','l3','l5','','l4','','','']
```

Both the lists have same number of elements. For every group of elements in 'a list I only want to replace the value in list b at index 1 of each group present in list a.

Conditions : Only replace the value in list b if the element at that index(of list a) is empty or '' in list b.

If the first value in list b with respect to group of values in list a at index 1 is not empty dont change the further values i.e If the list b has already some value present at index 1 dont replace any value of that group with respect to indexes in list a.

For example: a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]=b['','','l2,'l3','l4,'','',''] then expected output is b=['value','','l2','l3','l4','','','']

Expected Output:

```
['value', '', 'l2', 'l3', '', '', '', 'value', 'l3', 'l5', 'value', 'l4', '', 'value', '']
```

[Approach that I got suggested earlier by @Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013198/16343464) (which is correct)
but now I have a different requirement:

```
a=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
b=['','','l2','l3','','','','','l3','l5','','l4','','','']

from itertools import groupby
g = groupby(a)

i = 0
for group,data in g:
    n = len(list(data))
    b[b[i:i+n].index('')+i] = 'value'
    i+=n
    
    

print(b)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
['value', '', 'l2', 'l3', 'value', '', '', 'value', 'l3', 'l5', 'value', 'l4', '', 'value', '']
```

Comment: is this really [**your** approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73013198/16343464)?

Comment: Hey I know its yours, I tried asking you questions on comments in my earlier posts but you didn't reply. I'll edit and give you credit :)
Apologies!

Comment: This is actually not mine, and give so time to the author to respond. They might be working, asleep, offline… Also why did you use a new account?

Comment: Because i could not post new questions on my previous account. Could you please help me with this problem? Would appreciate a lot

Comment: @mozway Can you suggest your approach for this one?

Comment: How is it different from the previous question? please be explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use a simple test:

```
a=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5]
b=['','','l2','l3','','','','','l3','l5','','l4','','','']

from itertools import groupby
g = groupby(a)

i = 0
for group, data in g:
    if not b[i]:
        b[i] = 'value'  # or b[i] = group if you want the value in a
    i += len(list(data))
```

output: `['value', '', 'l2', 'l3', '', '', '', 'value', 'l3', 'l5', 'value', 'l4', '', 'value', '']`

Comment: thank you, I'm new to stackoverflow and coding so apologies for mentioning the previous post as my approach

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution makes use of for-loops:

```
final_list = b.copy()

for idx in range(len(final_list)):
    if idx == 0 or a[idx] != a[idx-1]:
        if not final_list[idx]: final_list[idx] = 'value'
```

Another solution uses list comprehension:

```
final_list = ['value' if ((idx == 0 or a[idx] != a[idx-1]) and not b[idx]) else b[idx] for idx in range(len(b))]
```

Which creates the following output:
`['value', '', 'l2', 'l3', '', '', '', 'value', 'l3', 'l5', 'value', 'l4', '', 'value', '']`